# Springboot GET API returned deleted value from oracle sql database table

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I wrote a springboot GET API that get all the rows from a SQL database table. It works well at first. However, after I deleted several rows from database table, then run the GET API again, it returns all the rows from the table, as well as the rows I just deleted.

Looks the delete transactions are not processed correctly. I checked the table in SQL developer, and verified the rows are deleted. Just not sure why the GET API still return these deleted rows.

Is that caused by delete transaction from sql developer not committed in springboot app? if that's the case, how I can trace the transactions processing in springboot?
.
my dao layer:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import app.entity.Restriction;

@Slf4j
@Repository
public class RestrictionDaoImpl implements RestrictionDao {

    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    private static final String GET_ALL_RESTRICTIONS = " SELECT * FROM RPO_RESTRICTION_CRITERIA ";
    private static final RestrictionRowMapper RESTRICTION_ROW_MAPPER = new RestrictionRowMapper();

    public RestrictionDaoImpl(@Qualifier("aeVaultNamedParameterJdbcTemplate") 
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    }

 @Override
    public List<Restriction> getAllRestrictions() {
        List<Restriction> restrictions = this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(GET_ALL_RESTRICTIONS, RESTRICTION_ROW_MAPPER);
        return restrictions;
    }
}
```

I checked my dao layer, and cannot find any error in my query and namedParameterJdbcTemplate. Is there other files/codes I need to check?

Comment: Are you using any caching solution?

Comment: Did you commit after running your delete query in database ?

Comment: @AnkurSaxena no I didn't. After I delete some rows in the table, I restated sql developer, then the deleted rows apeared again.  Could you tell me how to commit the changes in sql developer?

Comment: @TheImpaler yes, using redis caching

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart the IDE or else  add these two `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update spring.jpa.show-sql=true`
in your application.properties

Comment: The issue is likely DML related, messing with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` won't do much. What's more, having it set to other value than `none` can have severe consequences in production. Though `spring.jpa.show-sql` can help during investigation it most certainly has nothing to do with the issue either.

Comment: I think the delete transaction is not processed correctly in Springboot. Is there anyway to let springboot app synchronize with the delete transaction?

Comment: @Attila is that because the delete transaction is rollbacked in springboot app? or the delete transaction made in sqldeveloper is not commited in springboot app?

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample doesn't include `@Transactional` boundaries so I'm going to assume that you have them properly defined in the layer that you call your `@Repository` methods from, i.e. services or controllers.

I'm no Oracle expert but as far as I know Oracle doesn't allow dirty reads, i.e. a transaction can never read the uncommitted changes of a concurrent transaction. You say it "works well at first" which also suggests that you set and use `@Transactional` boundaries properly and the delete operation is in fact committed.

In any case, you can enable and check the database logs in order to confirm if both the delete and commit happen or not.

You also say that "the deleted rows appeared again" which implies that they were gone before, yet another indication that delete works. OTOH, this makes me think that there might be a third actor accessing and making changes to your database (the first would be your Spring Boot application, the second would be SQL Developer):

- Is your database remote?
- Is your database accessible by other developers or services?
- Is your database used by any automated processes such as tests running on a build machine that might restore the database before being run?
- Is there replication set up and are you by any chance connected to the replica that gets synchronized back with the source periodically?
- Finally, is it possible that you run a test that produces the data that keeps re-appearing?

Comment: yes. the database is remote. yes the database is shared in my team.

Comment: do I need to commits manually after I delete rows in Sql Developer?

Comment: I didn't use @Transactional in my springboot app

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a delete API and call it to delete data in the table. Then when I call getAllRestriction API again, the rows deleted by delete API are not returned. However, I still want to figure out why the rows deleted by Sql Developer are returned by getAllRestriction API, and after I restart the sql developer, the deleted rows appears again.

The problem solved. I found the sql developer's auto commit is off, so every time I deleted a row, the transaction was not committed. I added"commit;" in sql developer to commit manually, then the GET API won't returns deleted rows.